# android edit text issue showing blue line at bottom

Tags: android, android-edittext

I don't want this line in EditText see image [image: m]

is that because of android them color.
what should i do to remove this line.and I want the screen Them without ActionBar.

Comment: it means that `edittext` is focused..

Comment: this style of EditText show and if you don't wan this style make your custom EditText.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just add `android:background="#00000000"` to your `EditText` in XML file
Or `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`

Answer (score 1):

Change your theme. Refer [Android holo colors](http://android-holo-colors.com/).

Choose the color as per your application's design and download the zip file of resources.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a selector background to your edittext without any border. For borderless edittext I used the following code:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<solid android:color="#00000000" />

<stroke
    android:width="0dp"
    android:color="#ffffff" />

</shape>
```

Set `android:background="@drawable/borderless_edittext"`

Answer (score 0):

For the action bar, add this in onCreate:

```
supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); //<--- this line
setContentView(R.layout.myactivity);
```

Note that you have to put it before the setContentView.

You could use a `<TextView>` for the blue line, and make it editable:

```
android:editable="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

add `android:background="#80000000"` to your EditText in XML file

Or `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`

or you can make a xml drawable for edittext background  like  http://www.techiecommunity.net/Android/Android-EditText-Background-Example

Answer (score 0):

Use updated library:

```
style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
```

or add this line on your theme with `spinnerStyle` attribute. Or set your `backgroundTintColor` to transparent from your style.